# Comparar dos txt con php

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de comparar dos archivos txt con php y la verdad no puedo hacerlo ya intente de todo

este es mi codigo.

```
    <?php

$limpios = 'salida.txt'; // Utilizo el archivo generado de la salida para comparar con los registrados.
$reg = 'registrados.txt'; // File para comprar los registros (usuarios registrados);

$regdos = [];
$limpiosdos = [];

$registrado = 0;

if(!in_array($reg, $regdos) && !in_array($limpios, $limpiosdos)){
    $regdos[] = $reg;
    $limpiosdos[] = $limpios;

}

$resultado = array_intersect($regdos, $limpiosdos);

foreach($resultado as $ress){
    echo $ress;
}

echo 'Coincidencias: ' .  $registrado . '<br/>';
```

El problema es que si hay coincidencias pero no me devuelve nada.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno se me ocurre que lo hagas de la siguiente forma:

```
$limpios = file('salida.txt'); // Utilizo el archivo generado de la salida para comparar con los registrados.
$reg = file('entrada.txt'); // File para comprar los registros (usuarios registrados);

$resultado = array_intersect($limpios, $reg);
foreach($resultado as $ress){
    echo $ress;
}
echo 'Coincidencias: ' .  count($resultado). '<br/>';
```

Cuando pones el nombre de tus archivos debes usar `file()` para poder convertir su contenido a un `array`

Espero sea el resultado que esperas ;)